# Free online databases?

Tags: troubleshooting

I know there is AllDataDIY, but are there any free websites? With diagrams of where things are, or diagnosing and repair guides?

Comment: Can you make your question more specific? A question about a specific kind of information for a particular make/model of vehicle would make this question easier to answer, and more useful to those who come upon it later.

Comment: agreed - I have a Toyota Land Cruiser and find ih8mud.com very helpful, but they certainly don't have information about Volvos over there.  Also I think this site is intended to address some aspect of what you are asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be "enthusiast" groups for your specific car type.  These individual sites can often offer repair and diagnostics information, to varying levels of completeness, but I have never run across a make/model agnostic site that provides similar information.  Maybe this site in a few years?  :-)

Answer (score 2):

[Autozone](http://autozone.com) has vehicle repair guides and job diagrams, but only for some models/parts.